# How to prevent application in full screen mode to hide the taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

According to the number of search results people have problems hiding the taskbar in full screen mode. But I'm interested in the opposite, I don't want the application in full screen mode to use the taskbar space. Unfortunately Taskbar settings (Automatically hide the taskbar in [...] mode set to Off) are ineffective:

[image]

I'd live with autohide if some applications didn't prevent activating the bar by moving the mouse to the bottom (e.g. Youtube video in full screen mode).

Any solution (W10)?

Comment: I think this may be application dependent.  Office (365) Apps work fine in full screen (do not hide the task bar).

Comment: @John: Yes it is, and for Youtube (and video in a browser in general) it depends on the implementation of the [W3C Fullscreen API](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-requestfullscreen) Unfortunately W3C API doesn't protect OS areas and functionalities like OS mouse shortcuts.

Comment: You might try a (free) third-party tool such as Sizer (https://lifehacker.com/resize-your-windows-apps-to-any-dimensions-you-want-wit-1828124695) or and alternative (https://alternativeto.net/software/sizer/). One of these might let you set a shortcut to pre-size the window so that it doesn't cover the taskbar. That said, you'll likely have al the window decorations showing, too.